# How to stop maven-gwt-plugin from copying test scoped dependencies into target lib folder when running gwt:run

Tags: gwt, maven

When running mvn gwt:run all the test scoped dependencies are copied into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

I have tried using `runClasspathExcludes` in the gwt-maven-plugin configuration (see [sample project pom](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/expenses/pom.xml) for example) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The dependencies are marked as `<scope>test</scope>` in the pom and only get copied when running gwt:run (not when building the app).

I found this bug report on the gwt-maven-plugin Jira: [gwt:run does not use the 'runtime' scope's classpath](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-77). The last comments says:

> requiresDependencyResolution set to
>   "test" to ensure all artifacts are
>   available as dependencies when
>   building the classpath.

I think that means it uses the test scope to for the dependency resolution which would explain how the dependencies get there but the question is how to exclude certain dependencies?

Comment: Could be due to an older version of gwt-maven-plugin. Will upgrade and test again.

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Waiting for response from maven-gwt-plugin mailing list